# MIME-Typ-Conflict after deployment to Heroku (Vue.js with Express)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, heroku

i have a Vue.js App with Express, the App works fine on localhost but after i deploy the app i get a MIME-Type Error in my Browser (both, Chrome Version 114.0.5735.248 and Firefox 115.0.2), i use Node Version 14.18.0. When i access the deployed site i only see a blank page and get this Error:

**Firefox:**
Refused to execute script from '...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

**Chrome:**
Ressource was blocked: MIME-Typ-Confilct ("text/html"), (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

I only get this Error for .js files, sometimes only for one, sometimes for two, but when i refresh the site a few times, everything works perfectly. In my dist folder i have two .js Files, app.XXX.js and chunck-vendors.XXX.js, both in subfolder "js".

I already tried to explicitly set the content type for my JS files in server.js:
`app.get('*.js', (req, res, next) => { res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript;charset=utf-8'); next(); });`

The Heroku deployment works fine without any Errors, also i have installed all necessary build packs. In my public Folder i only have static.json, index.html and static.json, all Assets, Components, .vue Files, main.js, router.js and store.js are in my src Folder.

My vue.config.js looks like that:
`module.exports = { publicPath: '/', devServer: { allowedHosts: "all", }, runtimeCompiler: true, };`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.